# Combining a variable with html and inserting an output from a echo statment

Tags: php, variables, wordpress

I have a loan calculator plugin that has the below code block.  It sets the variable $calcHTML and then returns it to publish it to the screen.  It looks like a lot of code but it is really just putting a bunch of html to a variable then returning it.

I want to place my social button from another plugin in the middle of $calcHTML, so that my social button output on the calculator.

The code to output my social buttons is:

Social plugin code

```
if ( function_exists( 'rtsocial' ) ) { echo rtsocial(); }
```

How can I use the above function and combine it so that the output will be placed in the $calcHTML variable below?

Calculator code below

```
add_shortcode('clc_car_loan_calculator', 'clc_car_loan_calculator');

function clc_car_loan_calculator($atts) {

    $queryString = '';

    if(isset($atts['currency'])) {empty($queryString)?$queryString .= '?':$queryString .= '&amp;'; $queryString .= 'currency='.urlencode($atts['currency']);}
    if(isset($atts['theme'])) {empty($queryString)?$queryString .= '?':$queryString .= '&amp;'; $queryString .= 'theme='.urlencode($atts['theme']);}

    $calcHTML = '<div class="clc-widget clc-fp-widget">
                   <form>
                       <table class="clc-input-table">
                           <tr>
                               <td>Vehicle Price</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-price" />
                               </td>
                               <td>Down Payment</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-down-payment" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td>Trade in Amount</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-trade" />
                               </td>
                               <td>Owed on Trade</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-trade-owed" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td>Interest Rate</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-interest-rate" />
                               </td>
                               <td>Sales Tax Rate</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-tax-rate" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td>Term (months)</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-term" />
                               </td>
                               <td>Start Date</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-start-date" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td colspan="4">
                                   <input type="submit" id="clc-fp-calculate-car-loan-button" value="Calculate" onClick="return false;" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>
                   </form>
                   <table class="clc-fp-display-table">
                       <tr>
                           <td>
                               <h2>Loan Summary</h2>
                               <div id="clcFPCarLoanBreakdownData"></div>
                               <div class="clc-clear-line" style="height:20px;"></div>
                               <table class="clc-full-width">
                                  <tr>
                                     <td class="clc-breakdown-cell">
                                        <div id="clcFPCarLoanBreakdownChart" style="width:180px; height:180px;"></div>
                                     </td>
                                     <td class="clc-balances-cell">
                                        <div id="clcCarLoanPrincipleHeading" class="clc-heading"></div>
                                        <div id="clcCarLoanPrincipleChart" style="width:100%; height:180px;"></div>
                                     </td>
                                  </tr>
                               </table>
                               <div class="clc-clear-line" style="height:30px;"></div>
                               <div id="clcFPCarLoanAmortizationData">
                                   <ul>
                                       <li>
                                           <a href="#clcFPCarLoanYearlyAmortization">Yearly Amortization</a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li>
                                           <a href="#clcFPCarLoanMonthlyAmortization">Monthly Amortization</a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li>
                                           <a href="#clcFPCarLoanLoanDetails">Detailed Summary</a>
                                       </li>
                                   </ul>
                                   <div id="clcFPCarLoanLoanDetails"></div>
                                   <div id="clcFPCarLoanYearlyAmortization"></div>
                                   <div id="clcFPCarLoanMonthlyAmortization"></div>
                                   <div class="clc-clear-line"></div>
                               </div>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
                   <script src="'.plugins_url('/js/bootstrap-fp.js'.$queryString, __FILE__).'" id="clc-fp-car-loan" type="text/javascript"></script>
               </div>';

   return $calcHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( function_exists( 'rtsocial' ) ) { $calcvalue =  rtsocial(); }
```

And in your function

```
  function clc_car_loan_calculator($atts) {
global $calcvalue;
..
....
......
return $calcHTML.''.$calcvalue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

If you want to place some content in the middle you need to do it as follows

```
if ( function_exists( 'rtsocial' ) ) { 
    $calcHTML .=  rtsocial(); 
}
```

the `.` operaor is used for the concatination. Your whole function will now look like this

```
<?php
function clc_car_loan_calculator($atts) {

    $queryString = '';

    if(isset($atts['currency'])) {empty($queryString)?$queryString .= '?':$queryString .= '&amp;'; $queryString .= 'currency='.urlencode($atts['currency']);}
    if(isset($atts['theme'])) {empty($queryString)?$queryString .= '?':$queryString .= '&amp;'; $queryString .= 'theme='.urlencode($atts['theme']);}

    $calcHTML = '<div class="clc-widget clc-fp-widget">
                   <form>
                       <table class="clc-input-table">
                           <tr>
                               <td>Vehicle Price</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-price" />
                               </td>
                               <td>Down Payment</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-down-payment" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td>Trade in Amount</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-trade" />
                               </td>
                               <td>Owed on Trade</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-trade-owed" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td>Interest Rate</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-interest-rate" />
                               </td>
                               <td>Sales Tax Rate</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-tax-rate" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td>Term (months)</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-term" />
                               </td>
                               <td>Start Date</td>
                               <td>
                                   <input type="text" id="clc-fp-car-loan-start-date" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td colspan="4">
                                   <input type="submit" id="clc-fp-calculate-car-loan-button" value="Calculate" onClick="return false;" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>
                   </form>';

                   if ( function_exists( 'rtsocial' ) ) { 
                        $calcHTML .=  rtsocial(); 
                    }


    $calcHTML .=    '<table class="clc-fp-display-table">
                       <tr>
                           <td>
                               <h2>Loan Summary</h2>
                               <div id="clcFPCarLoanBreakdownData"></div>
                               <div class="clc-clear-line" style="height:20px;"></div>
                               <table class="clc-full-width">
                                  <tr>
                                     <td class="clc-breakdown-cell">
                                        <div id="clcFPCarLoanBreakdownChart" style="width:180px; height:180px;"></div>
                                     </td>
                                     <td class="clc-balances-cell">
                                        <div id="clcCarLoanPrincipleHeading" class="clc-heading"></div>
                                        <div id="clcCarLoanPrincipleChart" style="width:100%; height:180px;"></div>
                                     </td>
                                  </tr>
                               </table>
                               <div class="clc-clear-line" style="height:30px;"></div>
                               <div id="clcFPCarLoanAmortizationData">
                                   <ul>
                                       <li>
                                           <a href="#clcFPCarLoanYearlyAmortization">Yearly Amortization</a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li>
                                           <a href="#clcFPCarLoanMonthlyAmortization">Monthly Amortization</a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li>
                                           <a href="#clcFPCarLoanLoanDetails">Detailed Summary</a>
                                       </li>
                                   </ul>
                                   <div id="clcFPCarLoanLoanDetails"></div>
                                   <div id="clcFPCarLoanYearlyAmortization"></div>
                                   <div id="clcFPCarLoanMonthlyAmortization"></div>
                                   <div class="clc-clear-line"></div>
                               </div>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
                   <script src="'.plugins_url('/js/bootstrap-fp.js'.$queryString, __FILE__).'" id="clc-fp-car-loan" type="text/javascript"></script>
               </div>';


   return $calcHTML;
}
?>
```